# Prime Faces + Spring Security input values

Tags: java, spring, primefaces, spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented Spring Security + Prime Faces and everything works as excepted if my inputs (user & password) are **input** type.

Trying to improve the UI using "PrimeFaces Themes" I have replaced the **input** tags for **p:inputText** tags but the Spring Security stop working, I have debugged my application and I figured out that my back-end is getting blank values.

Does anybody know if I can use **p:inputText** instead of **input** tags with Spring Security?

As alternative I have thought to implement the Login UI using bootstrap and CSS.

Thanks I really appreciate your help

**It works**

```html
<p:panel id="loginPanel" header="Login" style="width: 30%"> 
               <h:form id="loginForm" action="${request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
                 <div align="center" >
                   <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorders" columns="2">  
                     <p:outputLabel value="Email:" />
                     <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
                     <p:outputLabel value="Password:" />
                     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                   </p:panelGrid>
                   <br/>
                   <p:panelGrid border="0" columns="1" styleClass="noBorders">
                     <p:commandButton onclick="document.getElementById('loginForm').submit()" value="Login"/>
                   </p:panelGrid>
                   <c:if test="${param.error}">
                     <h:outputText  style="font-size: 15; color: #FF1C19;" value="#{language.getMessage('login.error')}" />
                   </c:if>  
                 </div>
               </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

**It doesn't work**

```html
       <p:panel id="loginPanel" header="Login" style="width: 30%"> 
               <h:form id="loginForm" action="${request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
                 <div align="center" >
                   <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorders" columns="2">  
                     <p:outputLabel value="Email:" />
                     <p:inputText type="text" id="email" name="email" />
                     <p:outputLabel value="Password:" />
                     <p:inputText type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                   </p:panelGrid>
                   <br/>
                   <p:panelGrid border="0" columns="1" styleClass="noBorders">
                     <p:commandButton onclick="document.getElementById('loginForm').submit()" value="Login"/>
                   </p:panelGrid>
                   <c:if test="${param.error}">
                     <h:outputText  style="font-size: 15; color: #FF1C19;" value="#{language.getMessage('login.error')}" />
                   </c:if>  
                 </div>
               </h:form>
</p:panel>
```